# High temp castable refractory cement ok for molten silver?

Tags: material-selection, metalworking, jewelry, casting

Ive got a tub of Imperial brand *Castable Refractory Cement* and I'm wondering if it's able to withstand molten silver? Perhaps in casting jewelry or as a crusible.
The online product details are as follows;
"Repairs bricks and linings. Fast setting and non-asbestos. Can be cast into custom shapes or as one solid stove bed. Can be used indoors and outdoors. Resists temperatures up to 1204 Deg. C (2200 Deg. F)."

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. I'm not familiar with that product, so I'll leave this as a comment and just offer a couple of thoughts. The temperature range of the product is well above the melting point of silver, so that aspect wouldn't be a problem. But temperature isn't the only consideration. It could be fine for filling cracks or lining a stove bed. or cast in a solid shape. To use it for a mold or crucible, it can't be brittle and break when handled, and it needs to have a lot of tensile strength to not break from the outward forces from containing heavy, molten metal.  (cont'd)

Comment: I'd check with the manufacturer before using it for that purpose, or other people who are familiar with the product's characteristics and behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Silver melting at 1762 F plus some superheat; The product should tolerate the temperature if the info is correct. But a crucible also needs some strength, do you want to guess if the material would be strong enough? As commented by @fixer1234, intended use may be to cover fire brick. I would get a manufactured crucible like silicon carbide or ceramic. It would be messy if a crucible failed while holding molten silver.

Comment: Yeah, to use for a crucible, there are proven materials that would make more sense.  Being castable, there's an attraction for potential use to create a mold if the material is suitable.  It might also be possible to use it for a mold if the mold is strengthened with an external shell or embedded in sand.  Some of those concerns might be handled by using a suitable wall thickness.  @Sean, keep in mind that molten silver is not just potentially messy and expensive, it can be dangerous.